# Printing sys.stdout console on a "textBox" from customtkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, customtkinter

Good morning,
I want to print the console output on a textbox of a customtkinter object. The code is from here: [Github from TomSchimansky](https://github.com/TomSchimansky/CustomTkinter)

[image: Example image]

How can I sustitute the text "Lorem Ipsum ... etc" with the output of the console.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution:

Include that:

```
class StdoutRedirector(object):
    def __init__(self,text_widget):
        self.text_space = text_widget

    def write(self,string):
        self.text_space.insert('end', string)
        self.text_space.see('end')
```

and call the **textbox** like that:

```
sys.stdout = StdoutRedirector(self.textbox)
```

Now Im looking for do the same with stdin xd